# 405 error on Put and Delete on apache2.4

Tags: rest, apache2.4

this one has been driving me nuts for hours

you will sometimes get a seemingly nonsensical `405 Method Not allowed` when sending `DELETE` or `PUT` requests to Apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is seems that for `PUT` and `DELETE` requests apache will route them to a default handler if it can't find the resource you have requested

this means that the correct `404 Not Found` error is replaced by a `405` error

so if you are getting a `405` Error that doesn't make any sense check your URL very closely as you may have a minor typo, or as in my case falling foul of the fact that PHP curl doesn't support relative addresses